# API server not function ["The connection has been reset"]

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, ubuntu, timeout

I'm having some troubles with one of my servers. I've done an application with two servers, one the frontend that grabs the data of server API (Ubuntu server).

Well, yesterday had a lot of visits and the API server stop functioning but:

-I can do stuff in MySQL by SSH.

-The memory usage is ok.

-The logs are ok.

-The bandwitch usage is ok.

-If i restart the server or Apache2, function by some time (3-4 minutes).

And the most important i think if i tries to access to API (Is rest-style with http) it puts me the Firefox error "The connection has been reset".

I'd tried:

-Restart the server

-Restart Apache2

-Restart MySQL

-Viewed the logs of Apache2/MySQL

I don't know too much about systems so i don't know what to do more.

Comment: Among other things, it might be useful to know how your API is written - it seems likely to be PHP, but you don't say so. Are you using a framework (e.g. CakePHP)? More details would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conection-resets for HTTP connections like you're doing are usually the result of the web-server hanging up or outright refusing to connect. There are a couple of possible causes of this:

- The web-server is not listening on the port you think it is.
- The Front-end is trying to talk to the API server on a port you're not expecting.
- The web-server didn't actually start

  - You can verify this through `netstat -an` and looking for a listening service on the port you're expecting.